# How can I artificially slow down an FTP upload for testing purposes?

Tags: windows, internet-connection, bandwidth

I have some FTP upload software I'm trying to test, and I'd like to verify how it behaves over a very slow satellite link (~100-150 bytes per second).

How can I artificially slow down my very fast Ethernet link to simulate this? Are there any (free) programs that can limit the entire connection of for specific programs for Windows 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a program such as [NetBalancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) or [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).
Both should allow you to control individual upload speed per program, although they may have some limitations (like NetBalancer only allowing you to control the bandwidth of three programs without buying the full version).

In NetBalancer, all you have to do to throttle the upload or download speed of a certain application is right click on the program you want to throttle, and click the limit option under the "Upload" heading. A popup will then ask you what speed you want the program to be restricted to. This is NetBalancer:

[image: Net balancer screenshot]

If the above programs don't fit your needs, you can always have a look at [some of the best alternatives to them](http://alternativeto.net/software/netbalancer/).